# How is it possible that the statsmodels KPSS test rejects trend-stationarity but not stationarity?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statsmodels, kpss-test

take the time series in the code block below - if I run a KPSS test using `statsmodels` based on a regression around a constant (i.e. test for regular stationarity), I fail to reject the null at the 5% level (implying that the series is stationary). If I run it based on a regression with a trend line I reject it (implying that the series is trend stationary).

How is this possible? Surely a trend stationary series is also stationary, albeit with a flat trend line?

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import kpss

data = np.array([-0.08721753,  1.07007379, -0.86719441, -1.07140273, -0.71672431,
       -0.24154826,  0.61842641,  0.35725026,  0.83325037,  0.45607822,
        0.35844327,  0.1803253 ,  0.64200754,  1.89895813, -1.10932855,
       -0.47763873, -0.39872893, -0.2997073 , -0.24231703, -0.0639042 ,
        0.06203114, -0.39088078, -0.06973174, -0.25609183,  0.76782254,
        1.62122026, -1.22766646, -1.07834822, -0.36796001,  0.80402943,
        0.71627727,  0.87400175,  1.61415943,  0.64428729,  0.17785926,
        0.58174693, -0.81169869,  1.63257976,  1.33250503,  1.715958  ,
        0.84635771,  0.9797323 ,  0.55293248,  0.85130251,  1.36728755,
        0.92098767,  0.14946434, -1.01031496, -0.84492833,  0.98284348,
       -1.33074678, -0.67274008, -0.68831863, -0.20370696, -0.75731861,
       -0.72425902, -0.14741804, -1.42543703, -1.08332825, -1.26756238,
       -0.67092996,  0.38202756, -3.55378935, -1.83333887])

stationarity_test = kpss(data, regression='c', nlags="auto")
print('p-value (stationarity test) = ' + str(stationarity_test[1]))
trend_stationarity_test = kpss(data, regression='ct', nlags="auto")
print('p-value (trend stationarity test) = ' + str(trend_stationarity_test[1]))
```

p-value (stationarity test) = 0.07713799489092257

p-value (trend stationarity test) = 0.01